# Show a view in a layout without including other files in the view in AiryMVC framework?

Tags: php

If the view contains a header and footer, every view needs to include both in order to show properly.

For example, all my views have

```
include header.php

<div class="main">
   ... put the view here
</div>

include footer.php
```

Can we define a layout or template in AiryMVC so each view does not include header and footer but still shows the header and footer in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define layout that contains the view in the controller. Then, instead of using

```
$this->view->render();
```

You need to use

```
$this->layout->render();
```

in the controller.